# invoke bean method on p:dialog show

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, initialization

I need to call a bean method before a `<p:dialog>` is shown. Currently I have something like the following:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" action="#{someBean.init()}"
                 update="dialog-table" global="true" />
<p:dialog id="someDialog" modal="true" dynamic="false" onShow="updateDialog()">
    <ui:include src="some-dialog-content.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

Not too bad, and it even works, but there still is a problem. This dialog is shown via a call to `RequestContext` from Java code, and there is also a global `ajaxStatus` element which shows status dialog with a spinner when ajax call is sent and hides it when this call completes. However, `someBean.init()` may also take some time to complete, so I want to show this status dialog also when this `init()` is in progress (this is why I set `global` to `true` - as far as I understand, it should trigger `ajaxStatus`, and consequently, status dialog). However, this does not work. Status dialog is not shown during `someBean.init()` call.

As far as I can tell, this is happening because somehow this remove command is called before previous request (which resulted in `RequestContext` being updated and `someDialog` being shown) complete event was called. However, just after `someBean.init()` request is sent, this complete event is called, and status dialog vanishes before `someBean.init()` completes.

The only workaround I could find is second status dialog, copied from the main one:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog2" ...>...</p:dialog>
<p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" action="#{someBean.init()}"
                 update="dialog-table" global="true"
                 onstart="statusDialog2.show()" oncomplete="statusDialog2.hide()" />
<p:dialog id="someDialog" modal="true" dynamic="false" onShow="updateDialog()">
    <ui:include src="some-dialog-content.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

This works just as I need, but it is very ugly. Is there a way to do what I want in a more cleaner way?

I'm using JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 3.4.1.

Answer (score -1):

call the method before Requestcontext